# Reset/remove all styles for input, select and button across all browsers including mobile

Tags: css, select, button, input

I've searched all over for this but I can only find how to change/modify styles for input, select and button elements.

What I want to do is remove all shadows, borders, background, icons etc everything except the value itself, across all browsers and mobile.

Answer (score 54):

Simply:

```
input {
  all: unset;
}
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Comment: This is your answer.

Comment: This might lead to problems later, e.g. if you want to add outlines, Safari might ignore the specified with of an outline.

Comment: This answer is correct, but be very careful using it as it will also disable some important features like keyboard focus

Answer (score 24):

You can use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for improve the cross-browser rendering. You can update the following class in the normalize.css.

```
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea,html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],button[disabled],
html input[disabled],button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"], input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input[type="search"], input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration
```

Please add the following style to the above elements.

```
element {
    border:none;
    background-image:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, Ive just tried this on a jsfiddle and does not seem to work. Can still see the borders, icons etc on select, input etc

Comment: Doesn't seem very comprehensive.

Comment: Also you don't need `background-color: transparent` just `background: none`.

Comment: Please don't forget to set `color: black` or to any other sensible value, as it is not guaranteed to be black (e. g. some older versions of Firefox might set it to light colors when dark system theme is used).

Comment: also add `outline: none;`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to reset all the things, doing this for focus could also help:

```
.input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to completely clear the `input` use these styles

don't forget the `outline`

```
.my-input-class{
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  background-image:none;
  background-color:transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition of @dotslashroot 's `all: unset` for input type number you'll get arrows, to remove them with all the stylings you should use:

```
input{
  all: unset;
}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* For Firefox */
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Style the input tag via css.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

input etc.:

```
input, select, textarea {

}
```

Buttons:

```
input[type="submit"] {

}
```

**Reset the css**:
http://cssreset.com/

Nice looking reset:
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Thanks, yes I know you have to style it via css, but I am asking what is the css to remove ALL styling. so basically only that is left is the value/text. removing icons, shadows, background, border etc. across all browsers and mobile

Comment: That website you linked to makes you sign up to their newsletter to get CSS that's released freely on the web. Here is the most popular CSS reset: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/