# Using '-webkit-appearance:none;' to stop apple messing with CSS

Tags: css, html-select, webkit-appearance

So Apple/Safari have their own CSS for various elements like `<select>` or `<button>` tags.

I can get around this by using `-webkit-appearance:none;` but for my `<select>` this is removing the little drop down arrow too which I want to keep.

Is there a way around this to remove the other additional styling but keep the arrow, or else replace the arrow in a way that is going to be consistent across browsers?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476762/reset-remove-all-styles-for-input-select-and-button-across-all-browsers-includi

Comment: When you use `appearance:none`, you are instructing the browser to not apply *any* kind of styling on that element, so that unfortunately only includes removing the arrow. What you could do, though, is to use an inline SVG image (or any other image) in the data-uri as the background image.

Comment: I am re-proposing the above duplicate vote: [Reset/remove all styles for input, select and button across all browsers including mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476762/reset-remove-all-styles-for-input-select-and-button-across-all-browsers-includi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my comment, using `appearance: none` will actually strip all browser/OS-specific styling on the `<select>` element. That means that the dropdown arrow will also be removed, as different OSes will have different arrow styles, too.

What you can do is simply to provide your own background image for the arrow. This can be done by giving sufficient padding on the right side of the element, and then injected a background image.

The example below uses an [SVG arrow icon from Google Material Design](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=keyboard_arrow_down&style=baseline) as part of the [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/).

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  
  /* Add paddings to accommodate arrow */
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  
  /* Add arrow icon */
  /* Source: https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=keyboard_arrow_down&style=baseline */
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M7.41,8.59L12,13.17l4.59-4.58L18,10l-6,6l-6-6L7.41,8.59z"/><path fill="none" d="M0,0h24v24H0V0z"/></svg>');
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="Lorem" selected>Lorem</option>
  <option value="Ipsum">Ipsum</option>
  <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
  <option value="Sit">Sit</option>
  <option value="Amet">Amet</option>
</select>
```

Note: if you want to support IE, you will have to use encoded SVG markup in your data URI, i.e.:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; xmlns:xlink=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink&quot; width=&quot;24px&quot; height=&quot;24px&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 24 24&quot; xml:space=&quot;preserve&quot;&gt;&lt;path d=&quot;M7.41,8.59L12,13.17l4.59-4.58L18,10l-6,6l-6-6L7.41,8.59z&quot;/&gt;&lt;path fill=&quot;none&quot; d=&quot;M0,0h24v24H0V0z&quot;/&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;');
```